# Assign Data from child to parent in json object

Tags: json

**I had a object array containing items**

```
"0: Object
Entity: "Customer"
Id:   157
Message: "testMessage1"
Property: Object
Name: "LastName"
Rules: "NotEmpty""
```

Here, How could I pass Name value to Property

Name is act as key  within in Property object.

how could I Discard the Name and assign the value of Name i.e. (Last Name) to Property

This is what I have right now:

```
[
  {
    "Entity":"Customer",
    "Property": {"Name": "Email", "Type": "System.String" },
    "Rules":"NotEmpty",
    "Message":"ssdsdsds",
    "Id":157,
    "ValueToCompare": null,
  }
]
```

Here,  I need to assign  Name  value (i.e : Email) to Property Directly (it would be like this :-- `"Property": "Email"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you guys for your interest with this question.
At last I have write down the proper solution
My own solution to solve this problem is..**

In javascript :

```
function addProp(obj, propName) {
    for (var p in obj) {

        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {

            if (p == propName) {
                if (obj[p].Name == null) {
                    obj[p] = obj[p];
                }
                else
                {

                    obj[p] = obj[p].Name;
                }

            } else if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
                addProp(obj[p], propName);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Calling this function :

addProp(data, 'Property')

This work properly now

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is your json

```
[
{
    "0": {
        "Entity": "Customer",
        "Id": 157,
        "Message": "testMessage1"
    },
    "Property": {
        "Name": "LastName",
        "Rules": "NotEmpty"
    }
}
]
```

your original json contain in

> originaljson

and transform json contain in

> transformjson

```
JSONArray originaljson;
JSONArray transformjson=originaljson;
        for(int i=0;i<originaljson.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject mainJson=originaljson.getJSONObject(i);
            String name=mainJson.getJSONObject("Property").getString("Name");
            //mainJson.remove("Property");

            JSONObject mainJsonTransform=transformjson.getJSONObject(i);
            mainJsonTransform.remove("Property");
            mainJsonTransform.put("Property",name);
        }
```

now your transformjson contain the desired json

Comment: Thanks Angad ,     Could you write this code in plunker ?.  That will give me better understanding on this .

Comment: no... but the logic is same...copy the originaljson to transformjson..remove the jsonobject of key "Property"..and then add again with key "Property" with value retrieve from originaljson..

Comment: okkk. but I did not find JSONObject and JsonArray reffrence .

Comment: im not getting what you are trying to do.. you also have to show your work

Comment: the logic is same...my code is in java..you need to implement your in plunker..atleast try to syntax your program with this logic.